# Append an HTTP header to all IE requests

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, http, proxy, header

I have a scenario which requires me to append an HTTP header to all outgoing IE-based HTTP communications on a machine. This doesn't need to work outside of IE.

I first attempted to create a simple HTTP proxy in C#, but the performance of this proxy wasn't very good, and there were issues with HTTPS communications.

My second attempt was to use FiddlerCore, which I hoped would have better performance, but was only marginally faster than what I had created myself.

Aside from writing a TCP filter driver to do this (not in my skillset), is there another option? Strictly speaking, this doesn't have to be an HTTP header. It could even be something I tack on to the user agent string.

I was thinking perhaps about creating a simple BHO, but I'm hoping there is an easier solution... one that I can write in C# perhaps.

Comment: ok so you are trying to send a request from IE to a server and you want to somehow append a header to that request on the client side?  Can you not use browser detection on the Server end and handle the request accordingly?  Im sure im missing something, can you clarify it a little?

Comment: The scenario is actually that clients are connecting to web-based application running on a Citrix server. I need to include the original hostname (or IP) of the client connecting to Citrix so that my server application can then use that information. If I don't do this, the server always just sees the hostname of the Citrix server.

Answer (score 0):

How about just reading the user-agent string in your code and if it's IE then append the HTTP header?

Answer (score 0):

Just use user agent string. It is documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(VS.85).aspx .

Per article following registry key can be used to add to the user agent string: `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\User Agent\Pre Platform\Token = Value`.

Comment: This is an approach I thought about taking, but it's unreliable because the browser window must be closed and re-opened for IE to pick up those changes. In my case, a user is connecting to a Citrix server to run a web application in IE. I have some code to get the hostname of the PC connecting to the Citrix server and I then need to pass that (either as a header, or in the user agent, or whatever), to the target web application. Because this info changes depending on who is connecting to Citrix, and because sessions are often re-used, the browser window may not be closed/opened again inbetween

Comment: Are you doing ajax request (you can set headers there) or direct get in browser? One more option is to set cookie in the browser and it will be sent to server...

Comment: I have no control over the web application in question.